# How to check if FFmpeg process is complete

Tags: ffmpeg

How can I check if `ffmpeg` process is complete.
Like if I want to perform overlaying of image to video, I want to determine when the process is completed or if the output file is already complete.

So from this command

```
  ffmpeg -i original.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2" output.mp4
```

How can I determine if `output.mp4` is already complete.
Because if I have another function to transfer the output file somewhere, the transferred file is still incomplete by the time transfer is executed.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify how you're running `ffmpeg`: from bash or maybe from your code?

I will assume bash

In bash, when you run a process the way you run ffmpeg in your example, it will run in a sequential manner, so all you have to do is put your function right after the ffmpeg command line like so:

```
ffmpeg -i original.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2" output.mp4

echo "done!"
```

Comment: I am not sure that's working though. It seems like it is a noblocking... but, checking that atm.